# Magento 2 - How to apply Slick Slider to Recently Viewed Widget

Tags: magento2, layout, template, requirejs, widgets

I have created a code but slider is not showing up in recently viewed products.

Here is my code -

I have downloaded slick js and css from the following link http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Then i have done the following -

Step 1 -

> Copied slick.min.js and slick.js in
>
> app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/_YOUR_THEME_/web/js/

Step 2 -

> Create requirejs-config.js file in
>
> app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/_YOUR_THEME_/web/

with the following code in requirejs-config.js

```
    var config = {
    paths: {
        slick:        'js/slick'
    },
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Step 3 -

> Copied slick.less and slick-theme.less in
>
> app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/_YOUR_THEME_/web/css/source/

Step 4 -

> Clear cache and deploy files

Step 5 -

> Created viewed_grid.phtml in
>
> app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Reports/view/frontend/templates/widget/viewed/content

with the following code -

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed
 */
?>
<?php
if ($exist = ($block->getRecentlyViewedProducts() && $block->getRecentlyViewedProducts()->getSize())) {
    $type = 'widget-viewed';
    $mode = 'grid';

    $type = $type . '-' . $mode;

    $image = 'recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget';
    $title = __('Recently Viewed');
    $items = $block->getRecentlyViewedProducts();

    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $rating = 'short';
    $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
}
?>
<?php if ($exist):?>
    <div class="block widget block-viewed-products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $mode ?>">
        <div class="block-title">
            <strong role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
            <div class="products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $mode ?> <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $mode ?>">
                <ol class="product-items <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $type ?>">
                    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>
                        <div class="product-item-info">
                            <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                                <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="product-item-details">
                                <strong class="product-item-name">
                                    <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                       href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product-item-link">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
                                    </a>
                                </strong>
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                                    $_item,
                                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                                    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                                    [
                                        'price_id_suffix' => '-' . $type
                                    ]
                                ) ?>
                                <?php if ($rating): ?>
                                    <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $rating) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart): ?>
                                    <div class="product-item-actions">
                                        <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                        <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                                data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}'
                                                                type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <?php
                                                            $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                            $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                        ?>
                                                        <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                                data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                                type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare): ?>
                                            <div class="actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                                <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && $showWishlist): ?>
                                                    <a href="#"
                                                       class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                                       data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item) ?>'
                                                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Wish List') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php if ($block->getAddToCompareUrl() && $showCompare): ?>
                                                    <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');?>
                                                    <a href="#" class="action tocompare"
                                                       data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_item) ?>'
                                                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Compare') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?= ($iterator == count($items)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'slick'
    ], function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(".widget-viewed").slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 1280,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                            slidesToScroll: 3
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 768,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 2,
                            slidesToScroll: 2
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 600,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 1,
                            slidesToScroll: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    });
</script>   

<?php endif;?>
```

Step 6 -

> Clear cache and deploy files again

But the slider is still not showing up for recently viewed products in frontend

Please help me in correcting the code or creating a module to show recently viewed product with slick slider :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm currently attempting the same thing. From what I can tell I think the widget loads after my javascript has executed. I tried to wrap my code into a on document change listener but that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: I am also trying to apply slick slider in my magento. I referred many document they all are placed slick slider in theme. I am trying to place it in my custom module. Do you have any idea for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone else needs to do this, here's what I did for Magento 2.3.2. The Recently Viewed widget gets added via knockout, which fires after all the other javascript. So to apply slick I had to use the ["afterRender" custom binding](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html).

Once I found which knockout template and viewmodel js recently viewed products used it was pretty straight forward. Here's my code:

Copy `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/product/list/listing.js` to your theme like  `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/web/js/product/list/listing.js`

Make sure jquery/slick is added to the top of the script file, like so (this is assuming you've already added them to require-config.js):

```
define([
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/listing',
    'jquery',
    'slick'
], function (ko, _, Listing, $) {
```

Add a new function like so:

```
pdpRvSlickInit: function(){
        $('.block-viewed-products-grid .product-items').slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 960,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Now copy the knockout HTML template to your theme. Copy `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/template/product/list/listing.html` to `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/list/listing.html` I added a new Div, but I'm not sure you need to do that. I added this:

```
<div class="clear" data-bind="afterRender: pdpRvSlickInit"></div>
```

Before the last closing div. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

**You need to correct your step 2 make as below, Keep requirejs-config.js file in root of your theme instead of web folder.**

Create requirejs-config.js file in

```
app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/_YOUR_THEME_/
```

with the following code in requirejs-config.js

```
 var config = {
    paths: {
        slick:        'js/slick'
    },
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Run

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Hi Rakesh I have tried to put the requirejs-config.js in root of theme instead of web folder, but still slider is not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'slick'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".widget-viewed-grid").slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 1280,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                            slidesToScroll: 3
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 768,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 2,
                            slidesToScroll: 2
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 600,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 1,
                            slidesToScroll: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, this code is also not working. I have implied and tested.

Comment: you have given wrong class name check it!

Comment: Hi Ronak, I have checked with the above code ".widget-viewed-grid" and ".widget-viewed" these two classes, Still Slider is not showing. JS is loaded in requirejs-config.js correctly

Comment: Hi Ronak Tried by adding lot of other classes and it has taken my whole last day but still it is not running. Could you please suggest the correct class to make slider work with Recently Viewed Products.

Answer (score 1):

`requirejs-config.js` should be as below

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        slick: 'js/slick.min'
    },
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```